# Can  Muslim men and women shave their body? 

Tags: halal-haram, women, fiqh, men, human-body

In summer when going to Swimming, it can be quite embarrassment to go with hairy body. Also I do not personally like hairs on my body. I am not sure if Islam allows shaving the body?

If yes, can one shave the whole body or only any part of it?

What about Muslim women?

If they have this problem, can they shave too?

Answer (score 12):

The only hair areas that I am aware of that have restrictions are:

**The beard for men**

> Narrated By Ibn 'Umar : Allah's Apostle said, "Cut the moustaches
>   short and leave the beard (as it is)."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhary, The Book of Dress, Hadith Number:5954](http://www.hadithtranslations.com/ViewResultsFrame.aspx?sid=1890445392&setID=1&bookID=77&hadithID=5954)

**The eyebrows for women**

> Narrated By 'Abdullah : Allah has cursed those women who practise
>   tattooing and those who get themselves tattooed, and those who remove
>   their face hairs, and those who create a space between their teeth
>   artificially to look beautiful, and such women as change the features
>   created by Allah. Why then should I not curse those whom the Prophet
>   has cursed? And that is in Allah's Book. i.e. His Saying: 'And what
>   the Apostle gives you take it and what he forbids you abstain (from
>   it).' (59.7)
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhary, The Book of Dress, Hadith Number:5994](http://www.hadithtranslations.com/ViewResultsFrame.aspx?sid=-1406961769&setID=1&bookID=77&hadithID=5994)

Removing hair from the rest of the body is halal, and in some areas (arm pits and pubic area) it is *sunnah*.

> Narrated By Abu Huraira : I heard the Prophet saying. "Five practices
>   are characteristics of the Fitra: circumcision, shaving the pubic
>   hair, cutting the moustaches short, clipping the nails, and depilating
>   the hair of the armpits."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhary, The Book of Dress, Hadith Number:5952](http://www.hadithtranslations.com/ViewResultsFrame.aspx?sid=322291660&setID=1&bookID=77&hadithID=5952)

Answer (score -1):

Well, of course they can lol.
I personality dont shave but I trim my chest and the bottom of my stomach you know the area around my belly button, you can only see the little hairs when you're close to me... so I think that counts lol.
I shave my armpits (It's better if we shave it in our religion due to sweat and hygiene...). I used to shave my downstairs area to zero but then a girl told me that "it's nicer if it's trimmed" haha. So yea, it's okay.
I must say tho, most Muslim guys trim their bodies because it's more masculine, but all women shave.

Comment: Welcome on Islam stack exchange. This site is meant to give answers based on Islam. Personal views may be admitted in a last sentence but  not be the main content of the answer.